# Solution To A Slope Field

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am hoping to clear up a couple small points of confusion. I am a student and may not know all the proper mathematical terminology so please patient with me.

1) Is the Equilibrium line of a slope field the line the other slope "marks" angle towards or away from? (I hesitate to use the term converge or diverge here) For example the slope field for "dy/dx = x + y" has a steady line running through it at y=-x-1 that the other slope marks angle towards or away from it.

2) Is the equation for the equilibrium line mentioned in 1 above considered the 'solution' to the differential equation?

I thanks you for patients

Comment: What would a slope field be? The most reasonable translation would be a vector field (of a gradient or what not), but $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = x+y$ is an ODE, not a vector field.

Comment: Indeed, what you described is a [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Solutions) to the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = x + y$. The proper name for what you call "slope field" is [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) and the proper name for "equilibrium line" is [integral curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_curve#Definition).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Its given me good information. This is a topic that is my James Stewart calculus textbook and my prof. opted to cover it.